# How to reorder Android 8.0 language list in Welcome Page

Tags: android, locale

As we all know, google put en_US first in the list, so make it default in android\o-base\build\target\product\full_base.mk file, but I don't want to change this file, and I had found the language list setting in LocalePicker.java the method getAllAssetLocales() to load all kinds of languages. But if I add "en-US", it will be the first in the language list, even I do add them like this order:

```
localeList.add("zh-CN"); 
localeList.add("th-TH");
localeList.add("vi-VN");
localeList.add("my-MM");
localeList.add("fr-FR");
localeList.add("ru-RU");
localeList.add("zh-HK");
localeList.add("en-US");
```

And I had also disabled sort() it, but it isn't work, the "en-US" still in the first of language list. 
Anyone have another good idea? Thanks in advance.